# points in pointcloud after conversion don't have same accuracy as in ply file

Tags: point-clouds

I use potreeConverter 1.6 to convert my ply file to view it in potreeViewer. I get the mouse point using this method

```
var intersection = Potree.utils.getMousePointCloudIntersection(mouse, viewer.scene.getActiveCamera(), viewer, viewer.scene.pointclouds);
var point=intersection.point.position;
```

but this point hasn't same accuracy as point in ply file ?! I don't know why?

Comment: In what way does it not have the same accuracy? What is the accuracy in the file and what is the accuracy you're seeing in your code?

Comment: @user1118321 for example in ply file point = -7.775883 but from this code it equals -7.776388168334961